# Simple Bash Script that recursively searches in subdirs for a certain string

Tags: linux, bash

i recently started learning linux because a ctf contest is coming in the next months. The problem that I struggle with is that i am trying to make a bash script that starts from a directory, checks if the content is a directory or other kind of file. If it is a file,image etc apply `strings $f | grep -i 'abcdef'`, if it is a directory cd to that directory and start over. i have c++ experience and i understand the logic but i can't really make it work.I can't succesfully implement the loop that goes thru all the subdirectories. All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you don not need a loop for this implementation. The [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command can do what you are looking after.
for instance:

```
 find /home -type f -exec sh -c " strings {} | grep abcd " \;
```

explain:

`/home` is you base directory can be anything

`-type f`: means a regular file

`-exec`  from the man page:

> "Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All
> following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to
> the command until an argument consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string` {}' is replaced by the current
> file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the
> arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it
> is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these
> constructions might need to be escaped (with a `') or
> quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See
> the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the -exec
> option.  The specified command is run once for each
> matched file.  The command is executed in the starting
> directory.  There are unavoidable security problems
> surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the
> -execdir option instead."

Comment: Thank you very much. it looks like i over complicated stuff. Wish you the best!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just find the string in a file and you do not **HAVE TO** first find a directory and then a file and then search, you can just simply find the text with `grep`.
Go to the the parent directory and execute :
`grep -iR "abcd"`
Or from any place,
`grep -iR "abcd" /var/log/mylogs/`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not realised i could also go this way.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a `grep` command on `find` filter results:

```
 grep "abcd" $(find . -type f)
```